# What permission am I missing here?

Tags: docker

So I'm trying to setup a container for a project and I'm receiving an error during building. I'm very new with Docker. Can anyone help me understand this?

Here's the error:

```
[17181 ms] Start: Run in container: # Copy C:\Users\nathan\.ssh\known_hosts to /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
[17187 ms] 
[17187 ms] /bin/sh: 15: cannot create /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
[17187 ms] Exit code 2
[17194 ms] Command in container failed: # Copy C:\Users\nathan\.ssh\known_hosts to /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
(dd iflag=fullblock bs=8192 count=0 2>/dev/null; dd iflag=fullblock bs=968 count=1 2>/dev/null) >/home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts
[17194 ms] /bin/sh: 15: cannot create /home/vscode/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
```

And here is the dockerfile as requested:

```
    FROM ruby:2-alpine

ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV CA_CERTS_PATH /etc/ssl/certs
ENV RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT true
ENV RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES true
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG '.bundle'

EXPOSE 3000

RUN bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'
RUN bundle config set without 'development test assets'

RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

CMD ["bin/puma", "-C", "config/puma.rb"]

RUN gem install bundler -v '~> 2'

RUN apk add --no-cache \
  tzdata \
  busybox \
  ca-certificates \
  curl \
  imagemagick \
  libsodium-dev \
  postgresql-dev \
  postgresql-client \
  nodejs \
  rsync

COPY . $APP_HOME
COPY config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
```

Is this a network permission not allowing me to copy files? I'll supply more info as requested.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], probably including at least your image's Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are running the Docker build on a specific path that need administrator permissions , to resolve that just copy your project to the Desktop for example and try again :

```
docker build -t image_name:image_tag path_to_dockerfile
```

Notes:
image_name= app (example)
image_tag= 1.0 (example)
path_to_dockerfile= your current path where you has your Dockerfile , also you can put "." that mean the current path .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll do my best to follow this.

Comment: Just try and give me feedback I can support you

Comment: Okay so the building has completed in the terminal, but opening VS and trying to build it there still isn't working. 

In my json file, should I change the "WorkspaceFolder" to be  "Desktop" now?

Comment: yes , you should change the workspace